# Openpyxl: Zoom out from existing workbook

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I would like open an existing Excel file, go through all available sheets and zoom out (level 85%) on all sheets. Afterwards save it again. I use Openpyxl (version 2.4.0) but it seems to be impossible. Either I get a error message or it runs but I havn't any changes.

My steps are:

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook(excelFile)

    for eachSheet in wb.worksheets:

     eachSheet.zoom = 85
     #views.zoomScale= 60

    wb.save(excelFile)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the zoom on the *worksheet view*, not on the worksheet directly.

The code would be something like:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(excelFile)
for ws in wb.worksheets:
     ws.sheet_view.zoomScale = 85
wb.save(excelFile)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. How could you identify the correct syntax? I have checked the documentation of Openpyxl but it couldn't find it...

Comment: Glad it works for you! I was able to track it down in the code from a comment on the issue: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/262/set-the-zoom-of-a-sheet